# ffmpeg best parameteres for fastest compression on FullHD mp4?

Tags: ffmpeg, compression

I need to compress a bunch of FullHD(1920x1080, 3Gb, mp4) videos, each ~2 hrs long. Some loss of quality is okay as is the lower resolution. I'm shooting for a 500Mb output video in ~10 min processing time (2080TI Ryzen 9 3900X). It is important for the videos to be completely in sync, so frame x in the input video matches frame x in output. For this, I'm using `-vsync 0`

My current working settings which get me to ~500MB size in 20 minutes.

`ffmpeg -i input_fullhd.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 -vsync 0 -vf scale=800:-1 -preset medium output.mp4`

I'd like it to be faster with potentially slightly better quality.

My concern is that I'm not utilizing my GPU at all and my CPU shows only 30% utilization. So feels like it should be possible to speed this up. I tried adding `-hwaccel cuda` but that made things a bit slower.

Are there any other settings I can try that I'm missing to either improve my conversion or utilize more resources for speed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the GPU, there is a different codec `hevc_vaapi` or `hevc_nvenc`. You can see some examples [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/VAAPI) and [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro). I got it to work once but the quality was much more terrible, so I didn't use it much.